# Count the rows affected by plpgsql function

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, count, plpgsql

I have the following function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION user_delete(IN id INT4)
  RETURNS VOID
AS
  $BODY$
  BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM "user" WHERE user_id = id FOR UPDATE;
    DELETE FROM user_role WHERE user_id = id;
    DELETE FROM user_permission WHERE user_id = id;
    DELETE FROM permission_cache WHERE user_id = id;
    DELETE FROM access WHERE user_id = id;
    DELETE FROM "user" WHERE user_id = id;
  END;
  $BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

I use this with PHP PDO:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM user_delete(?)');
$stmt->execute(array($user['id']));
```

The result contains now

```
array(
    array('user_delete' => '')
)
```

and so the

```
$stmt->rowCount();
```

is always one.

Is it possible to fix this: by the function return nothing (because it is void), and by the rowCount return the count of the affected rows?

**Solution:**

php:

```
public function delete($id)
{
    try {
        $this->__call('user_delete', array($id));
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() === 'UE404')
            throw new NotFoundException();
        else
            throw $e;
    }
}
```

sql:

```
CREATE FUNCTION user_delete(IN id INT4)
  RETURNS VOID
AS
  $BODY$
  BEGIN
    DELETE FROM user_role WHERE user_id = id;
    DELETE FROM user_permission WHERE user_id = id;
    DELETE FROM permission_cache WHERE user_id = id;
    DELETE FROM access WHERE user_id = id;
    DELETE FROM "user" WHERE user_id = id;
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
      RAISE SQLSTATE 'UE404' USING MESSAGE = 'not found for delete';
    END IF;
  END;
  $BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

I can achieve return zero length result with `setof void` return type, but that is not necessary if I force it to throw `PDOException` when the resource is not found ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
GET DIAGNOSTICS integer_var = ROW_COUNT;
```

.. and let the function return the count. [Details in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS)

Example:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION user_delete(id int, OUT del_ct int)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   i int;  -- helper var
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM user_role WHERE user_id = $1;
   GET DIAGNOSTICS del_ct = ROW_COUNT;  -- init

   DELETE FROM user_permission WHERE user_id = $1;
   GET DIAGNOSTICS i = ROW_COUNT;  del_ct := del_ct + i;

   DELETE FROM permission_cache WHERE user_id = $1;
   GET DIAGNOSTICS i = ROW_COUNT;  del_ct := del_ct + i;

   DELETE FROM access WHERE user_id = $1;
   GET DIAGNOSTICS i = ROW_COUNT;  del_ct := del_ct + i;

   DELETE FROM "user" WHERE user_id = $1;
   GET DIAGNOSTICS i = ROW_COUNT;  del_ct := del_ct + i;
END
$func$;
```

You had this as 1st statement:

```
SELECT * FROM "user" WHERE user_id = $1 FOR UPDATE;
```

Invalid syntax - inside a plpgsql function you need to use `PERFORM` for `SELECT` statements without target:

```
PERFORM * FROM "user" WHERE user_id = $1 FOR UPDATE;
```

- [SELECT raises exception in PL/pgSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37230750/select-raises-exception-in-pl-pgsql-function/37234043#37234043)

But the ensuing `DELETE` statement locks the row just as well. No need for [manual locking with `FOR UPDATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) to begin with.

The added `OUT del_ct int` declares an `OUT` parameter that can be assigned like any variable and is returned at the end of the function automatically. It also obviates the need for an explicit `RETURNS` declaration.