# Setting variable in a Postgres function

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, variable-assignment, plpgsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "freeTicket" (eid integer NOT NULL)

DECLARE
    couponCode text 
BEGIN


INSERT INTO purchases p (cid, pdate, eid, ccode) 
VALUES
(
  SELECT p.cid, GETDATE(), $1, couponCode FROM purchase p
  GROUP BY p.cid
 HAVING COUNT(1) > 5
  ORDER BY p.cid
);

END; LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I need to set the variable of `couponCode` to the output of:

```
Select code from couponCode where eid = $1 and percentage = 100;
```

And use it in the insert query above.
What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

That would be `SELECT <expressions> INTO <variables> FROM ...`, but you can do it all in one statement:

```
INSERT INTO purchases p (cid, pdate, eid, ccode) 
   SELECT p.cid,
          current_date,
          $1,
          (SELECT code FROM couponcode
           WHERE eid = $1 AND percentage = 100)
   FROM purchase p
   GROUP BY p.cid
   HAVING COUNT(1) > 5:
```

`ORDER BY` makes no sense here.

Answer (score 1):

Basics about assigning variables in PL/pgSQL:

- [Store query result in a variable using in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328198/store-query-result-in-a-variable-using-in-pl-pgsql/12328820)

Apart from that, your function has a number of syntax errors and other problems. Starting with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "freeTicket" (eid integer NOT NULL)

DECLARE ...
```

- `NOT NULL` isn't valid syntax here.
- You must declare the return type *somehow*. If the function does not return anything, add `RETURNS void`.
- For your own good, avoid CaMeL-case identifiers in Postgres. Use legal, lower-case identifiers exclusively if possible. See:

  - [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

The function would work like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION free_ticket(_eid integer, OUT _row_ct int) AS
$func$
DECLARE
   coupon_code text;  -- semicolon required
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO purchases (cid, pdate, eid, ccode)
   SELECT cid, now()::date, _eid
       , (SELECT code FROM couponCode WHERE eid = _eid AND percentage = 100)
   FROM   purchase
   GROUP  BY cid
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 5  -- count(*) is faster
   ORDER  BY cid;       -- ORDER BY is *not* pointless.

   GET DIAGNOSTICS _row_ct := ROW_COUNT;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The added `OUT row_ct int` is returned at the end of the function automatically. It obviates the need for an explicit `RETURNS` declaration.

You also had a table alias in:

```
INSERT INTO purchases p (cid, pdate, eid, ccode)
```

But [`INSERT` statements require the `AS` keyword for aliases](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html) to avoid ambiguity (unlike other DML statements). So: `INSERT INTO purchases AS p ...`. But no need for an alias since there is no ambiguity in the statement.

Related:

- [Count the rows affected by plpgsql function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193450/count-the-rows-affected-by-plpgsql-function/18194241#18194241)

Asides: Two tables named `purchase` and `purchases`, that's bound to lead to confusion. And the second table might also be replaced with a [`VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html) or [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html).