# Don't round float input silently when inserting into integer column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I have a table like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo(bar int)
```

I have a script which inserts values into that table:

```sql
INSERT INTO foo(bar)
VALUES (1), (2), (3.2)
```

The float value is silently rounded to fit the data type:

```
> SELECT * FROM foo;
 bar
-----
   1
   2
   3
(3 rows)
```

Is there anything built-in to Postgres which can prevent this from happening and, instead, raise an error? (Or even a warning?)

Comment: Neither a check like check `(bar % 1 = 0)` in the table definition nor a `before insert trigger` will allow you obtain the "source data", because in both cases `3.2` has been converted to `3` previously (due to type definition and implicit conversion). So, not sure if is possible to do what you want. The following link will provide more information about it https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194975/how-to-avoid-implicit-type-casts-in-postgresql

Comment: Have you tried dropping the assignment cast from `float8` to `integer`?

Comment: << spends an hour reading dense [type-conversion documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/typeconv-oper.html). Decides to stop thinking about ths issue forever >>

Comment: Just when I am about to commit an answer to make you think about it some more. :p

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter lol. No, I'm actually really interested (and I'm still reading the docs despite my earlier comment!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numeric constant `3.2` initially resolves to data type `numeric` (not `float`). Details in the manual [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-NUMERIC).

The assignment to an `integer` columns works silently because there is an "assignment" cast registered for `numeric` --> `integer` in standard Postgres.

To get the desired behavior, you would have to hack a warning into the function that implements the cast in the Postgres source code (and recompile). A very high price to pay. (What about version updates?)

Or you remove or change the registered cast. You could replace the cast with a version based on your own function - and raise a `WARNING` in there. But that's expensive, and may spam *a lot* of warnings.

You don't want to remove that cast completely. Lots and lots of calculations use it.

#### Workaround?

You *could* use this simplistic workaround: disable the cast for the transaction only:

```
BEGIN;

UPDATE pg_cast
SET    castcontext = 'e'               -- make the cast "explicit"
WHERE  castsource = 'numeric'::regtype
AND    casttarget = 'integer'::regtype;

INSERT INTO foo(bar)
VALUES (1), (2), (3.2);

UPDATE pg_cast
SET    castcontext = 'a'               -- revert back to "assignment"!
WHERE  castsource = 'numeric'::regtype
AND    casttarget = 'integer'::regtype;

COMMIT;
```

Now, an exception is raised in case of actual `numeric` input.
**But** you need superuser privileges to do that. You might encapsulate it in a `SECURITY DEFINER` function. Related:

- [Is there a way to disable updates/deletes but still allow triggers to perform them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886529/is-there-a-way-to-disable-updates-deletes-but-still-allow-triggers-to-perform-th/17887101#17887101)

And you don't want to lock the system catalog `pg_cast` for long while concurrent operations can happen. So I'd rather not do that with concurrency around.

#### Solution?

You could move input values to a CTE and test in a `WHERE` clause to skip inserts (silently) if they aren't all valid integer values:

```sql
WITH input(i) AS (
   VALUES (1), (2), (3.2)  -- one numeric makes all fall back to numeric
   )
INSERT INTO foo (bar)
SELECT i
FROM   input
WHERE  (SELECT pg_typeof(i) FROM input LIMIT 1) = 'integer'::regtype;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cde983bb9810332efc644fcc98447605)*

You could then check the command tag whether anything was inserted.

Or wrap it all in a plpgsql function, check whether anything was actually inserted, and `RAISE` whatever you need if not. Related examples:

- [Count the rows affected by plpgsql function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193450/count-the-rows-affected-by-plpgsql-function/18194241#18194241)
- [How to programmatically check if row is deletable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390754/how-to-programmatically-check-if-row-is-deletable/19393268#19393268)

Comment: This is really interesting stuff. It's important to know about this kind of blood-and-guts detail of how Postgres works. We're still developing a green-field project so we _could_ potentially get away with this solution.  But I suspect most people will read this and conclude that trapping the input in scripting is the best way forward.

Comment: @LondonRob: I added another possible solution.

Comment: Nice. This is the kind of serious pg_wizardry I enjoy.